# Объединение строк разных столбцов

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, обработка-данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К примеру, имеем такой DataFrame. Можно ли с помощью внутренних методов объединить состав заказов, если дата покупки совпадает?

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'Дата заказа № 1': ['10.02.19', '09.11.19', '15.01.19'],
 'Состав заказа № 1': ['рыба', 'бананы', 'гречка'],
 'Дата заказа № 2': ['11.02.19', '09.11.19', '21.02.19'],
 'Состав заказа № 2': ['fish', 'beans', 'bread'],
 'Дата заказа № 3': ['01.12.19', '09.11.19', '25.03.19'],
 'Состав заказа № 3': ['конфеты', 'мёд', 'молоко'],
 'Дата заказа № 4': ['01.12.19', '12.11.19', '27.05.19'],
 'Состав заказа № 4': ['овощи', 'макароны', 'птица'],
 'Дата заказа № 5': ['01.12.19', '12.11.19', '25.09.19'],
 'Состав заказа № 5': ['мясо', 'фасоль', 'хлеб']},
 columns=['Дата заказа № 1', 'Состав заказа № 1','Дата заказа № 2', 'Состав заказа № 2','Дата заказа № 3', 'Состав заказа № 3','Дата заказа № 4', 'Состав заказа № 4','Дата заказа № 5', 'Состав заказа № 5'])'
```

По-хорошему, мне надо получить лист листов с заказами:

```
my_list=[['рыба'], ['fish'], ['конфеты','овощи','мясо'], ['бананы', 'beans', 'мёд'], ['макароны', 'фасоль'], ['гречка'], ['bread'], ['молоко'], ['птица'], ['хлеб']]
```

Но я пришёл к выводу (возможно, ошибочному), что проще сначала объединить заказы в самом фрейме данных, а уже потом "выцепить" их циклом.

Ориентировочно, хотелось бы получить такой фрейм, но итоговый результат может и отличаться от приведенного ниже: для меня достаточно объединить заказы одной даты в одну строчку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вроде неплохой вопрос, но из-за картинок вместо текста вынужден воздержаться от голосования "за".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Работать с данными в таком (широком) формате очень неудобно. Лучше сделать UNPIVOT и получить фрейм с двумя столбцами `Date` и `Item` - с таким форматом работать будет гораздо проще:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("\s*№.*$", "", regex=True)
t = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date": df.loc[:, "Дата заказа"].stack().reset_index()[0], 
    "Item": df.loc[:, "Состав заказа"].stack().reset_index()[0]
})
```

промежуточный результат:

```
In [214]: t
Out[214]:
        Date      Item
0   10.02.19      рыба
1   11.02.19      fish
2   01.12.19   конфеты
3   01.12.19     овощи
4   01.12.19      мясо
5   09.11.19    бананы
6   09.11.19     beans
7   09.11.19       мёд
8   12.11.19  макароны
9   12.11.19    фасоль
10  15.01.19    гречка
11  21.02.19     bread
12  25.03.19    молоко
13  27.05.19     птица
14  25.09.19      хлеб
```

теперь эти данные можно легко сгруппировать:

```
res = t.groupby("Date")["Item"].apply(list).reset_index()
```

результат:

```
In [216]: res
Out[216]:
       Date                    Item
0  01.12.19  [конфеты, овощи, мясо]
1  09.11.19    [бананы, beans, мёд]
2  10.02.19                  [рыба]
3  11.02.19                  [fish]
4  12.11.19      [макароны, фасоль]
5  15.01.19                [гречка]
6  21.02.19                 [bread]
7  25.03.19                [молоко]
8  25.09.19                  [хлеб]
9  27.05.19                 [птица]
```